# Feature Driven Development in the work place?

Tags: project-management, agile

**Question**
Please explain Feature Driven Development in a nutshell?

**Situation**
My Business Analyst calls their documentation FDD, but it just seems overwhelmed by details.

**In a Nutshell**
An 'in a nutshell' example would be good, since I'm trying to reduce unnecessary detail and confusion. I want to add clarity, and an Occam's' razor approach to the documentation.

Thanks for your help,

[Here's what I found](http://agile.dzone.com/articles/introduction-feature-driven)

Comment: "good"?  Define "good" please.  You have a resource.  What's not "good" about it?

Comment: Does anybody wish to help me understand Feature-Drive-Development?

Comment: @FXquincy: Define "good" please. You have a resource. What's not "good" about it?  What don't you understand?  What more do you need?  What part confuses you?  We don't know what it takes to help you understand.  We don't know you very well.

Comment: corrected, see question

Comment: @FXquincy: Define "good" please.  You've amplified what you want, but we still don't know what you consider "good".  Detailed?  Expensive?  Long?  Short?  Color Graphics?  Animations?

Comment: @S.Lott, Explaining a methodology in a nutshell is good. Books like The Agile Samurai are good...short explanations, simple graphics. Examples of how to diagram FDD would be good. 'Detailed' may be the nature of FDD, but simple is what's 'good' for understanding new concepts. It got me thinking. What's you're thoughts?

Comment: @FXquincy: I don't have thoughts on this.  I'm asking what you define as a good.  Please **update** the question with your definition of good.   ("simple", "nutshell", whatever.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an entire website dedicated to the subject: http://www.featuredrivendevelopment.com/ it even recommends [books](http://www.featuredrivendevelopment.com/books).

Maybe your Business Analyst could share a little of his/her knowledge with you? Asking questions is a strength.